# How to get lists of tasks associated with each executor in apache storm?

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I am exploring Apache Storm. I need to know how can I get list of tasks which are associated to each executor in a node in apache storm.  For instance, consider a simple topology with 1 spout and 2 bolts:

Spout -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2

If there is a 3 node cluster, and numworkers = 3, is there any way of determining how tasks are associated and grouped with the executors?

Comment: What task will go to which bolt or worker, that will depend on which grouping you are using while creating the topology. If it's shuffle grouping then any task can assign to any worker at runtime. Please check with grouping in storm.

Comment: I know the grouping policies, but my question is how to get the total number of tasks associated with executor in a JVM?